# What is visible in the output file as a result of name mangling?

Tags: c++, c++11

Are only public functions visible after name mangling ? What happens to private, and protected functions ? What about class member variables, constants, enums etc ? Nested classes ?

I am aware that each compiler mangles differently, but I imagine they mangle the same things ? Is that right ?

After compiling a class, how do I inspect the output file to see what is visible ?

For example, if i have the following class, and it is compiled, when can an end user determine just by inspecting the output file (they won't have access to the source code).

```
class SomeSwearWord{

private:
     int _anotherSwearWord;
     int getNextSwearWord();
protected:
     std::string _aCurseWord;
     std::string refineMyCurseWord();
public:
    int _aVeryBadWord;
    int getPreviousBadWord();
}
```

EDIT: For purposes of example, let us consider LLVM or gcc...

EDIT: Will a customer, who has no access to the source code, be able to determine the above curse words just from the executable or object files ?

EDIT: Can anyone give a comprehensive answer ? The actual platform doesn't matter, I'm just trying to get an idea of what is visible. I understand that different compilers mangle differently, but I just want to understand in the worst case, how much can an outsider see ?

Comment: How to examine an object or executable file depends on your compiler and platform.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just for my conceptual understanding, the actual platform does not matter. I just want some idea of whether my function names and variable names can be determine by the end user...

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but usually most of this stuff ( namespaces, class and member names + function arguments) will be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All things that may need to be relocated are visible in the output file. So that's anything that has a fixed position in the resulting binary.

- Members are not visible.
- Nonvirtual Member functions are visible
- Virtual member functions are visible
- Class names are probably visible, in that their constructor will need to be called somewhere, or that their name is part of the full function name.
- Static members are visible
- Static member functions are visible.
- Enumerations, structs, unions and classes themselves are not present at all.
- C strings (ie, `"MyString"`) are not present as symbols, but as read-only data.

So in your example, no members would be visible, but all functions would be - if they are called.

Virtual function names are present, because your vtable is an array with relocations to all your virtual functions.

You can suppress their presence in the output file by having a definition file when linking that contains the exact list of outputs you want present. On Windows this is the default (ie, everything's hidden) for shared libraries, but on Linux/Mac the default is making them visible and overrideable.

When talking about "name mangling", we're actually talking about how to convert a function instantiation, with template stuff, arguments and so on into one unique string. The names themselves that are mentioned are there verbatim and unmangled.

For example, your example would result in the following symbols (GCC):

```
_ZN13SomeSwearWord16getNextSwearWordEv
_ZN13SomeSwearWord17refineMySwearWordEv
_ZN13SomeSwearWord18getPreviousBadWordEv
```

Note that the return types are not present. You can get this from your object files or executable files with `objdump -t <myBinary>`

Comment: what happens to things like C enums, and string literals ?

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that these function names were present for the benefit of the linker... but why does the linker need to know about private function names ?

Comment: When you define your class in multiple files (which is valid and legal) it needs to be able to tie the call to the implementation. Private/public/protected are concepts that apply only at compile time, but that have no effect at link time (aside from some very odd platforms).